# Make Team City Ignore Commits -- By comment

Tags: metadata, teamcity

I have a TeamCity project with a build step that updates some metadata in our csproj files in source control.

These commits are marked with the comment "Build Server".

Is there anyway to make TeamCity ignore such commits for the purpose of establishing whether there are any changes pending.

I have filtered this out of the trigger so that I don not get an infinite build loop but would like to not even have "pending changes" listed until a commit with a different comment arrives.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think such a feature exists in Teamcity today. There are `checkout rules` for the `VCS Settings`, but that works on the folders only (i.e. you need to mention the folders to be excluded in that case). There is an open request on checkout rules http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3460. You may want to check that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the trigger rules on the vcs build trigger. There is a help icon that describes the rules, but if it helps, here's a copy of my rules:

```
-comment:.*\*$:**/*
-:ldap/**
-:schema/**
-:scripts/**
-:**/*.jsp
-:**/*.css
-:**/*.html
-:**/*.png
-:**/*.pdf
```